# Aligning text element width with image element resides in same container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a web app using React with bootstrap and trying to implement a card box which contains a text and an image element.

Though the image size is unknown until an image is fetched through external API (flickr etc...) I would like to set the size of entire card box is adjusted to the size of fetched image and also makes the text element get adjusted to its size.

My current implementation partially addresses that requirement above but the issue is that the text element takes too much width space and not adjusted itself to the image size.

I have been trying possible attributes to resolve this but could not figure out yet so I appreciate any suggestion..!

[image]

Current Structure:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row text-center">
          {
              this.props.photos.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <div className="col-md-3" key={`Photo_${index}`}>
                    <div className="card-box" key={`Photo_${index}`}>
                      <div>
                        <p>{item.title}</p>
                      </div>
                      <img src={`${item.media.m}`}/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              })
          }
          <div className="clearfix" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Current Style:

```
.card-box {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #888888;
}

.card-box p {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

.card-box img {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the css `max-width` property? You can specify the max width of the column container your image and text.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `display:table` properties to let an element expand to the widest one.

To force the boxe to be be as small as possible , you need to set a small value for `width`, `0` can even be used.

Do not use `table-layout:fixed;` together, it will not expand anymore.

example

```css
.squeezeIt {
display:table;
width:0; /* will expand width according to the widest content*/
margin:auto;/* mind behavior here */
}
/* inline-table can also be used */
.squeezeIt + .squeezeIt {
display:inline-table;
margin:5px;
}
/*makup*/
.squeezeIt {
border:solid;
padding:5px;
}
p {
margin:0;
text-align:justify;
text-align-last:justify;
}
body {
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="squeezeIt">
<p>Some random text  up here</p>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x50" />
</div>
<div class="squeezeIt">
<p>Some random  </p>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50" />
</div>
<div class="squeezeIt">
<p>Some random text showing </p>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50" />
</div>
<div class="squeezeIt">
<p>Some random text showing up here</p>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x50" />
</div>
<div class="squeezeIt">
<p>Some random  </p>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/40x50" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired layout only via CSS, but you can use JavaScript here. Demo:

```js
var cardBoxImages = document.querySelectorAll(".card-box > img");

for (var i = 0; i < cardBoxImages.length; i++) {
  var cardBoxImage = cardBoxImages[i];
  var cardBox = cardBoxImage.parentElement
  cardBox.style.width = cardBoxImage.offsetWidth + "px";
}
```

```css
.card-box {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  /* specify width only by content */
  box-sizing: content-box;

  /* centering for text and image */
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* just styles for demo */
  outline: 1px solid yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-boxes">
  <div class="card-box">
    <div class="card-box__text">Short text</div>
    <img class="card-box__image" src="https://placehold.it/200x300/a00/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="card-box">
    <div class="card-box__text">This text container contais very long text</div>
    <img class="card-box__image" src="https://placehold.it/250x175/a00/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="card-box">
    <div class="card-box__text">This text container contais very long text. This text container very long text.</div>
    <img class="card-box__image" src="https://placehold.it/250x175/a00/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="card-box">
    <div class="card-box__text">This text container contais very long text. This text container very long text.</div>
    <img class="card-box__image" src="https://placehold.it/250x175/a00/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="card-box">
    <div class="card-box__text">This text container contais very long text. This text container very long text.</div>
    <img class="card-box__image" src="https://placehold.it/250x175/a00/fff"></div>
  <div class="card-box">
    <div class="card-box__text">This text container contais very long text. This text container very long text.</div>
    <img class="card-box__image" src="https://placehold.it/100x100/a00/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="card-box">
    <div class="card-box__text">This text container contais very long text. This text container contais very long text. This text container contais very long text. This text container contais very long text. This text container contais very long text. This text container very long
      text.</div>
    <img class="card-box__image" src="https://placehold.it/400x600/a00/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```